# Ubuntu Problems in 12.04 and 13.10 on the Sony Vaio Fit

Tags: 12.04, 13.10, graphics, soundcard, sony

I got this Sony Vaio Fit SVF15A1C5E and I am now trying to get one of these Ubuntu releases to work.

First off with Ubuntu 13.10 its graphics card did not work. It worked with 13.10 until I got a black screen and started of with Ubuntu 12.04 and the sound did not work.

I did everything I could find on Google, Ask Ubuntu, Ubuntu Wiki, and so on.
I got a couple of total freezes with the only thing working was force shutdown.

I updated  the kernel to get it to work then I got another black screen and now back also on 13.10.

My question is: which problem is easier to solve and how?

Answer (score 0):

Dual graphic cards have always been a problem with linux but fixable if you look at this website and go to step 4 on the list:

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/8-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.

...also I'd stick with Ubuntu 13.10 for the latest driver support, more precisely Xubuntu 13.10 for a lighter and less power consuming desktop...

Comment: the link you sent dosent work. (found it on google)
and have to add that the nvidia work fine in 12.04 nothing i needed to do and it showed.

Comment: Now i tried : sudo apt-get install nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 nvidia-prime. and got a nice black screen and no desktop.